# Tyrus sometimes stuck when trying to connect

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

I'm using the `tyrus-standalone-client-1.12.jar` to maintain a connection to a Websocket server (or set of servers) I have no control over. I'm creating a `ClientManager` instance that I configure and then use `clientManager.asyncConnectToServer(this, new URI(server))`, where `this` is the instance of a class with annotated methods like `@OnOpen`, `@OnMessage` and so on.

I also have a `ClientManager.ReconnectHandler` registered that handles `onDisconnect` and `onConnectFailure` and of course outputs debug messages.

Most of the time it connects just fine, but especially when the server has issues and I loose connection, reconnecting sometimes doesn't work.

I first noticed it when I simply returned `true` in `onDisconnect` and it just wouldn't reconnect sometimes (which in this case the `ReconnectHandler` should have done for me, which it usually did as well). The rest of the program keeps running just fine, but my websocket client just wouldn't do anything after the debug message in `onDisconnect`.

Since then I changed it to only use the `ReconnectHandler` to just connect again via `asyncConnectToServer` (on a delay), in order to be able to switch to another server (I couldn't find a way to do that with just the `ReconnectHandler`). Even then, the `asyncConnectToServer` sometimes just seems to not do anything. I'm sure it does *something*, but it doesn't output the debug message in `onConnectFailure` and also doesn't call `onOpen`, even after hours, so the client ends up just being stuck there.

Again, this isn't always the case. It can reconnect just fine several times, both triggered by `onDisconnect` or by `onConnectFailure`, and then on one attempt suddenly just hang. When I had two instances of the program running at the same time, both reconnected a few times and then both hang on `asyncConnectToServer` at the same reconnect attempt, which for me seems to indicate that it is caused by some state of the server or connection.

One time it even failed to connect when intially connecting (not reconnecting), during the same time where the server seemed to have issues.

- Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?
- Am I missing some property to set a connection attempt timeout?
- Am I missing some way to retrieve connection failure info other than `ReconnectHandler.onConnectFailure`?
- Am I even allowed to reuse the same `ClientManager` to connect several times (after the previous connection closed)?
- Could there be something in my client endpoint implementation that somehow prevents `onOpen` or `onConnectFailure` to be called?

It's kind of hard to tell what's going on without getting any error message and without being able to reproduce it. I used JConsole's Detect Deadlock button on the program with a client hanging like this and it didn't detect anything (not sure if it would, but I thought I'd mention it).

Comment: I know this might be a longshot, but .. can you by any chance provide a reproducer?

Comment: I'm really not sure how to do that since it appears to depend on the server state, and I don't know enough about Websockets to even guess what the issue might be.